# In the below code ,which part describes Timer is fired every 60 second?

Tags: embedded, attiny

```c
void TCA0_init()
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV256_gc| TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bm; ;  // Set prescaler to 256
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_NORMAL_gc;  // Set timer mode to normal
    TCA0.SINGLE.CNT = 0;                              // Initialize the timer count
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;           // Enable TCA overflow interrupt
     uint16_t ticks = 781249;                       //3.33MHZ*60/256
     TCA0.SINGLE.PER = ticks - 1;
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sei();
}

//volatile uint8_t timerCount = 0;

ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect)
{ 
    timerCount++;
    
    if (timerCount == 120)  // Fire the timer every 60 seconds (120 overflows)
    {
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
        PORTB.OUT |= PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
    
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN3_bm;
        
    timerCount = 0;  // Reset the timer count
    
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;
}
}
```

```c
void TCA0_init()
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV256_gc| TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bm; ;  // Set prescaler to 256
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_NORMAL_gc;  // Set timer mode to normal
    TCA0.SINGLE.CNT = 0;                              // Initialize the timer count
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;           // Enable TCA overflow interrupt
     uint16_t ticks = 781249;                       //3.33MHZ*60/256
     TCA0.SINGLE.PER = ticks - 1;
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sei();
}

//volatile uint8_t timerCount = 0;

ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect)
{ 
    //timerCount++;
    
    //if (timerCount == 120)  // Fire the timer every 60 seconds (120 overflows)
    //{
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
        PORTB.OUT |= PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
    
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN3_bm;
        
  //  timerCount = 0;  // Reset the timer count
    
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;
//}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, tell us about your own findings, and where your understanding stops. -- Oh, and you have two versions of your source. Which one is the one you use?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  But one serious bug in this code is that the ticks value of 781249 is too great for a uint16_t.  A uint16_t has a maximum value of 2^16 = 65536.  If you change the prescaler from 256 to 4096 then you could use a tick value of 3.33MHz*60/4096=48779, which fits in a uint16_t.

Comment: Yeah got it  as the timer need to be fired every 60 seconds and the ticks value is exceeding the 16 bit reg value and its 3.33MHZ frequency and 256 prescaler.So i have added timer count in ISR routine.Please let me know is the ISR rountine correct?If not then what are the changes to be made??